# Is there a way to set global settings for all Swift Package Manager dependencies?

Tags: xcode, swift3, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I added GoogleSignIn with SPM however, I get 2 warnings (See attached). I know that the issue has to do with the values set on the Package.swift file of the dependency.

I have been browsing around to find a way to fix the issue but, I have yet to find any results.

WARNINGS:

[image]

Please let me know if anybody has found or knows how to fix these warnings.

Thank you!!